# Please tell me what's wrong in my code.Trying to connect .mdf database with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

I am a begginer and want to use .mdf database (Service based Database) in Visual Studio.

I have a very less to NO knowledge about using SQL SERVER. I have once used MySQL.
The app on a different PC. So, I shifted on SQL SERVER DATABASE FILE which will be in the project itself.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\databse.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataTable dtbl=new DataTable();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT*FROM tbl",con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dtbl = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtbl);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtbl;
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

This code is supposed to show data from the database when button1 is clicked.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please edit your question to include the error, if any, or what happened when you ran the code?

Comment: I used try catch loop.

Comment: still No exception message was shown

Comment: But the Data Was not shown in the Datagrid

Comment: Is the Connection String Correct.

Comment: I have no Idea using connection strings.I just followed steps from youtube videos.